# Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1 - Data from API to be created in multiple Sitecore Folders

Tags: data-exchange-framework

Using Sitecore 9.0.1, and DEF 2.0.1, we have pipelines set-up which read attributes from an API, and then update / create an attribute item in Sitecore:

[image]

We now need to change this so that attributes of type A are created in folder AA and attributes of type B are created in folder BB etc. i.e. the data returned from the api is created in Sitecore in different folders dependent on the value of a type field.

My first thought was that it would involve a custom implementation of ResolveSitecoreItemStepProcessor. However, this would require path settings for folders AA, BB etc. to specify the path to the folder to contain created items and would seem to be overly complex. Could something be done at the Iterate  Rows from Source and Run Pipeline step instead with a custom implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add one more pipeline step before **Resolve Attribute Item**.

Call it **Resolve Item Parent for Attribute**.

As I understand your **Resolve Attribute Item** is **Resolve Sitecore Item** pipeline step. That means that this pipeline step has a setting **Parent for Item Location**.

Your task is in **Resolve Item Parent for Attribute** resolve and put the parent to a location and in the resolver, pick up resolved item from the location.